# Enum and Dictionary<Enum, Action>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enums

I hope I can explain my problem in a way that it's clear for everyone.
We need your suggestions on this.

We have an Enum Type which has more than 15 constants defined.
We receive a report from a web service and translate its one column into this Enum type.
And based on what we receive from that web service, we run specific functions using
Dictionary

Why am I asking for ideas?
Let's say 3 of these Enum contants meet specific functions in our Dictionary but the rest use the same function. So, is there a way to add them into our Dictionary in a better way rather than adding them one by one? I also want to keep this structure because when it's time, we might have specific functions in the future for the ones that I described as "the rest".

To be more clear here's an example what we're trying to do:

Enum:

```
public enum Reason{
    ReasonA,
    ReasonB,
    ReasonC,
    ReasonD,
    ReasonE,
    ReasonF,
    ReasonG,
    ReasonH,
    ReasonI,
    ReasonJ,
    ReasonK
}
```

Defining our Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<Reason, Action<CustomClassObj, string>> ReasonHandlers = new Dictionary<Reason, Action<CustomClassObj, string>>{
    { Reason.ReasonA, HandleReasonA },
    { Reason.ReasonB, HandleReasonB },
    { Reason.ReasonC, HandleReasonC },
    { Reason.ReasonD, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonE, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonF, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonG, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonH, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonI, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonJ, HandleReasonGeneral },
    { Reason.ReasonK, HandleReasonGeneral }
};
```

So basically what I'm asking is, is there a way to add **Reason, Function** pair more intelligently? Because as you can see after ReasonC, all other reasons use the same function.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: This calls for a `switch` unless you have some dynamic requirement.

Comment: Are you saying you might get a set of values, and if the set contains both ReasonD and ReasonE, you want to run HandleReasonGeneral only once?

Comment: for ReasonD and ReasonE I want to call the same function. But I want to add that function into the dictionary in an efficient way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try something like this, only put the custom Reason handler in the dictionary and then fallback to the General one.

```
public Dictionary<Reason, Action<CustomClassObj, string>> ReasonHandlers = new Dictionary<Reason, Action<CustomClassObj, string>>{
    { Reason.ReasonA, HandleReasonA },
    { Reason.ReasonB, HandleReasonB },
    { Reason.ReasonC, HandleReasonC }};


public Action<CustomClassObj, string> ReasonHandlerLookup (Reason reason) {
    Action<CustomClassObj, string> result = null;
    ReasonHandlers.TryGetValue(reason, out result);
    return result ?? HandleReasonGeneral;
}
```

Comment: The indexer will throw a KeyNotFoundException if the key doesn't exist.  It's better to use TryGetValue() instead.